# Legrand Orange Book bibliography categories

Tags: biblatex

I am using the Legrand Orange Book template a project, and I have a problem with the bibliography.

I have changed the bibliography definition to this:

```
%------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY AND INDEX
%------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[style=numeric,citestyle=numeric,sorting=nyt,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,babel=hyphen,hyperref=true,abbreviate=false,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} % BibTeX bibliography file
\defbibheading{bibempty}{}
```

This gives me a basic numbered bibliography like `[1]`, `[2]` etc. which is fine.

My problem is the categorization. Only books and articles appear in the bibliography, links to web pages don't, even though the numbered reference appear throughout the report.

An entry from by .bib file could look like this:

```
@misc{stat-downloads,
title = {{Number of free and paid mobile app store downloads worldwide from 2011 to 2017 (in billions)}},
url = {https://www.statista.com/statistics/271644/worldwide-free-and-paid-mobile-app-store-downloads/{\%}0A},
urldate = {2016-12-10}
}
```

The `.bib` file is generated by Mendeley.

I don't really care about the categories, I'd rather just have a long, numbered list. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Note that you (or Mendeley) shouldn't escape characters in the URL when given in the `url` field. That field is read verbose and can deal with special characters. You only need `url = {https://www.statista.com/statistics/271644/worldwide-free-and-paid-mobile-app-store-downloads/},` anwyway.

Comment: @moewe Yes, Mendeley has a habit of messing up URLs in bibtex. Thanks for pointing out the problem with that also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the version of [The Legrand Orange Book *template* from LaTeTemplates.com](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/the-legrand-orange-book) we find in `main.tex`

```
\chapter*{Bibliography}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textcolor{ocre}{Bibliography}}
\section*{Books}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Books}
\printbibliography[heading=bibempty,type=book]
\section*{Articles}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Articles}
\printbibliography[heading=bibempty,type=article]
```

If you simply replace that with only

```
\printbibliography
```

you should be good to go. You should get only one (combined) bibliography then.